# trouble understanding difference in 'find' output for bash using prompt, positional parameters

Tags: bash, positional-parameter

So I am trying to understand the difference between two results in Bash to further my understanding of positional parameters:

```
$ find ./*.md
one.md
two.md
three.md
four.md
```

and:

```
$ ./findall.sh ./*.md
one.md
```

where `findall.sh` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
find $1
```

In my understanding, these two should operations should be identical, but the use of positional parameters seems to return only one item. What am I not getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, your interactive bash is expanding `./*.md` before calling `find`. So your first command expands to this:

```
find ./one.md ./two.md ./three.md ./four.md
```

In the second case, your command expands to this:

```
./findall.sh ./one.md ./two.md ./three.md ./four.md
```

Then the script runs, and expands the command in the script to this:

```
find ./one.md
```

Perhaps you meant to quote the wildcard:

```
find './*.md'
./findall.sh './*.md'
```

But in either case, `find` will fail because the first arguments to `find` (before any arguments that start with `-`) are the names of directories in which to search. There is no directory whose name is `./*.md`, because `/` cannot occur in a file or directory name.

Perhaps you meant this, to find all files whose names match `*.md`, anywhere under the current directory:

```
find . -name '*.md'
```

Perhaps you meant this, to find all files in the current directory (but not subdirectories) whose names match `*.md`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.md'
```

Comment: Thanks Rob! Good explanation.

Comment: I've added some suggestions for `find` commands that might do what you want.